# Highcharts not showing value when two stacked columns have value = 1

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to show numbers in my Highcharts stacked columns. I have this issue that can be seen [in my left column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGaFN.png). When there are two small numbers together only one is shown.

This issue didn't happen with big numbers.

**I've tried this so far:**

- yAxis logarithmic and min: 0:

  ```
       yAxis: {
       min: 0,
       AxisTypeValue:'logarithmic',
       title: {
           text: 'Texto Cantidad'
       },
       stackLabels: {
           enabled: false,
           style: {
               fontWeight: 'bold',
               color: ( // theme
                   Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                   Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
               ) || 'gray'
           }
       }
   },
  ```
- This is my PlotOptions

  ```
       plotOptions: {
       column: {
           grouping: false,
           stacking: 'normal',
           dataLabels: {
               enabled: true,
               formatter: function(){
                   var val = this.y;
                   if (val < 1) {
                       return '';
                   }
                   return val;
               }
           }
       }    
   },
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by default anti-overlap behaviour for data labels. To display both data labels enable the `allowOverlap` option.

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            ...,
            dataLabels: {
                allowOverlap: true,
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k4vojwea/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels.allowOverlap